# error TS2322: Type 'Comment[]' is not assignable to type 'Comment[]'

Tags: typescript

I must be missing something completely obvious I simply do not understand the error.

Error message:

```
wwwroot/app/comments/commentList.ts(25,13): error TS2322: Type 'Comment[]' is not assignable to type 'Comment[]'.
Type 'Comment' is not assignable to type 'Comment'.
wwwroot/app/comments/commentList.ts(25,13): error TS2322: Type 'Comment[]' is not assignable to type 'Comment[]'.
Type 'Comment' is not assignable to type 'Comment'.
Property 'ID' is missing in type 'Comment'.
```

Component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'blog-comment-list',
   templateUrl: './app/comments/commentList.html'
})
export class CommentList implements OnInit {
    @Input() contentItemID: number;
    private comments: Comment[];

    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private blogService: BlogService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.blogService.GetCommentsForContentItem(this.contentItemID).subscribe(x => {
            this.comments = x;  // *** BUILD ERROR HERE ***
        });
    }
```

}

Service:

```
GetCommentsForContentItem(contentItemID: number): Observable<Comment[]>
{
    let url = this.serviceURL + 'GetCommentsForContentItem?contentItemID=' + contentItemID.toString();
    return this.http.get(this.noCache(url))
        .map(response => this.extractData(response))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMsg = error.message || 'Server errorx';
    console.error(errorMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
}

private noCache(url: string): string
{
    if (url === null || typeof (url) === 'undefined')
        return null;

    if (url.slice(-1) === '/')
        url = url.slice(0, -1);

    let connector = url.includes('?') ? '&' : '?';

    url = url + connector + 'noCache=' + (Math.random().toString().replace('.', ''));
    return url;
}
```

Model:

```
export class Comment {
    public ID: number;
    // more properties
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "samsblog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.12",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code for `extractData`?

Comment: BTW if by some strange chance any typescript team members should accidently read this post:  the number following 1.8.9 is not 1.8.10.... LOL funniest thing I ever saw https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases

Comment: Last time I checked `10` came after `9`

Comment: code added per your request.  I checked with my wife who is a PhD (not kidding) she teaches statistics at the college level... she confirmed that when incrementing by .1 the number following 1.8.9 is 1.9.0  (its all good we just thought it was funny)

Comment: Maybe you are referencing different `Comment` types in the two files? As for the version, `1.8.9` isn't a number, it's a release name where `1` is the `Major`, `8` is the `Minor` and `9` is the `Patch`.  The fact that you increment the patch doesn't mean you have to increment the minor.

Comment: I only have one comment class in the entire project. Thanks for clearing up the numbering!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about it, this is just a guess.

In your `extractData` method you're doing:

```
return res.json() || []
```

Where `res` is [angular Response object](http://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Response-class.html) and according to the docs the [json() method](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Response-class.html#!#json-anchor) returns `any`.

More than that, your `Comment` is a class not an interface, so you can't just take a json and return it as `Comment` even if there's a complete match with properties between them.

You'll need to do:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }

    return (res.json() || []).map(commentJson => new Comment(commentJson));
}

interface CommentJson {
    ID: number;
    // more properties
}

export class Comment {
    public ID: number;
    // more properties

    constructor(json: CommentJson) {
        this.ID = json.ID;
    }
}
```

Again, not sure that this is your problem, but from the code you posted it seems like you have those issues.

Comment: Nitzan, thank you very much for your insight.  I have many services like the one shown and they have all been working fine.  I suspect this may be an issue with visual studio as I just noticed that .map files are appearing differently in my project.  It used to be that files appeared in a hierarchy as .html -> .ts -> .js -> .map (I may have the order wrong but they appeared in a hierarchy and now they do not).